# Jquery $.post call to Mysql through PHP gives error: ReadResponse() failed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

in my application I am using Jquery `$.post` methods to a PHP page where I am making Mysql DB calls and with the return I am creating divs in a loop, finally returning that to Jquery $.post method and appending the output to HTML div tag. I have 8 different areas and for each area I am using separate Jquery `$.post` method sending different parameters to that PHP file. Every thing works fine but when I try to refresh the page for 3-5 times(quickly pressing refresh button) the page breaks, if I keep fiddler2 open is shows:

```
"[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.Server returned 0 bytes."
```

If fiddler2 is not open then it shows:

```
"The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."
```

I am using OOP PHP to connect to Mysql, checking if there is a live connection or not, after query execution I am closing the connection as well. Is it because of too many separate calls to server from separate Jquery $.post methods?

**Jquery $.post method:**

```
$.post('app_code/pageOperations/homepage.php', {
    articleTypeID: 1, //param for PHP page
    articleDate: today, //var holds today's date, param for PHP page
    position: "body" //param for PHP page
    },
    function(output){                     $("#politicsTop5").html(output);                  
    }
);
```

I have 8 methods with different data parameters.

**PHP code**

```
if($position == "body"){
    $_page_interface = new page_interface();    
    $result = $_page_interface->getArticleBody( $articleTypeID, $articleDate );
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {       
        echo "<div id='politics'>
        <div class='article-item alert alert-success'>
        <figure class='pull-left'><img src='".$row['speaker_img_link']."' alt='".$row['speaker_designation']." ".$row['speaker_name']."' /></figure>
        <div class='pull-right article-content'>
        <h4><a href='single_article.php?aId=".$row['article_id']."&typeId=".$row['article_type_id']."' title=''>".$row['article']."<br>- <b>".$row['speaker_designation']." ".$row['speaker_name']."</b></a></h4>
        <p class='article-meta'><b>".$row['TotalUp']."</b> <i class='icon-thumbs-up'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$row['TotalDown']."</b> <i class='icon-thumbs-down'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$row['TotalComment']."</b> <i class='icon-pencil'></i></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
}
```

All those 8 Jquery methods call this PHP block with different parameters.
All works fine but after couple of refresh the data won't load. Can any one help me please? Thanks in advance.

**PHP code block Edit:**

```
if($position == "body"){
        $_page_interface = new page_interface();    
        $result = $_page_interface->getArticleBody( $articleTypeID, $articleDate );
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {       
            echo "<div class='politics'>
            <div class='article-item alert alert-success'>
            <figure class='pull-left'><img src='".$row['speaker_img_link']."' alt='".$row['speaker_designation']." ".$row['speaker_name']."' /></figure>
            <div class='pull-right article-content'>
            <h4><a href='single_article.php?aId=".$row['article_id']."&typeId=".$row['article_type_id']."' title=''>".$row['article']."<br>- <b>".$row['speaker_designation']." ".$row['speaker_name']."</b></a></h4>
            <p class='article-meta'><b>".$row['TotalUp']."</b> <i class='icon-thumbs-up'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$row['TotalDown']."</b> <i class='icon-thumbs-down'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$row['TotalComment']."</b> <i class='icon-pencil'></i></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: to put your code inside code block, select your code and press  CTRL + K

Comment: thank you for that, this was my first ques here, I missed that part.

Comment: Your PHP/HTML code is wrong, you add an element with an `id` in every cycle, but IDs must be unique (by definition). Your error messages assume that the PHP instance crashes, so you might need to increase the memory limit?

Comment: that was actually a very good point, I should not have multiple div ids with same name, I've edited that thank you. Now where do I increase the memory limit? I definitely don't have access to server php.ini file, could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: either in a php file, .htaccess file or just the php.ini file if you have access to it.  If it's the .htaccess you can set `php_value memory_limit 128M` and for the php.ini it's just `memory_limit = 128M`.  http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php for more detail

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've hosted this app on godaddy, not sure if I have access to any of those files, any way I will contact them. Again are we certain that this is the problem? or there might be something else?

Comment: So apparently the issue got solved, it was all about the server settings I guess, I've hosted my application to another server and it works fine. It does not die if I keep on hitting the refresh for 5/6 times... Thank you everyone for pointing out things I missed :-)